# (C++) Como abrir multiples archivos usando fstream

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
  DIR *dir;
  ifstream file;
  string line; 
  struct dirent *ent;
  string appdata = std::getenv("appdata");
  string ldb = appdata+"/some/path/..."; 
  dir = opendir(ldb.c_str());

  if (dir) { 
  while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
      cout << ent->d_name<<"\n";
  }
  } else {
      void exit();
  }
}
```

El codigo devuele todos los archivos en el directorio, pero no puedo encontrar la manera de abrir todos los archivos para ver su contenido, necesitaria un poco de ayuda con fstream, perdonen el mal codigo.

Comment: Pues tienes montones de ejemplos en internet. Empieza con uno y cuando tengas alguna duda concreta con alguno, entonces vienes y pones la pregunta que necesites. Suerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tienes motivos para usar [`std::fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) para abrir archivos, tienes dos versiones de flujo de datos de/a archivo según si quieres leer o escribir:

- [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream): Lectura desde acrhivo (**i**nput **f**ile **stream**).
- [`std::ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream): Escritura en acrhivo (**o**utput **f**ile **stream**).

Para leer el contenido de un archivo:

```
if (std::ifstream archivo{"ruta/archivo.txt"})
{
    // Operaciones con el archivo.
}
else
    std::cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo\n";
```

Si quieres leer varios archivos a la vez, sólo debes crear más flujos:

```
std::ifstream archivo1{"ruta/archivo1.txt"};
std::ifstream archivo2{"ruta/archivo2.txt"};
std::ifstream archivo3{"ruta/archivo3.txt"};
std::ifstream archivo4{"ruta/archivo4.txt"};
std::ifstream archivo5{"ruta/archivo5.txt"};

if (archivo1 && archivo2 && archivo3 && archivo4 && archivo5)
{
    // Operaciones con los archivos.
}
else
    std::cout << "No se pudieron abrir los archivos\n";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso ayuda bastante!